# How to synchronize Cuda across different branches?

Tags: c++, cuda, synchronization

I've got data I wish to process with Cuda C++ where I operate on four pixels at a time, the four pixels all share a corner.  E.g., I'd operate on four `+` pixels together for all locations in the field:

```
------------
--------++--
--------++--
------------
------------
```

Therefore, to avoid memory collisions, I've decided to run my work in four flight, where each flight is able to run in parallel without colliding with other threads since no two threads are simultaneously working on any of the same pixels:

```
// We break the threads up into four flights:
//
//     0: even X and even Y
//     1:  odd X and even Y
//     2: even X and  odd Y
//     3:  odd X and  odd Y
const int flight = ( threadIdx.x % 2 + ( ( threadIdx.y % 2 ) << 1 ) );

for (int idx = 0; idx < flight; ++idx) {
  __syncthreads();
 }

doWork( pixel[ threadIdx.x +     threadIdx.y * blockDim.x ],
        pixel[ threadIdx.x + 1 + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x ],
        pixel[ threadIdx.x + 1 + (threadIdx.y + 1) * blockDim.x ],
        pixel[ threadIdx.x +     (threadIdx.y + 1) * blockDim.x ]);

for (int idx = 3; idx > flight; --idx) {
  __syncthreads();
 }
```

The goal is to break up the work into four flights that are synchronized with each other, something like this:

Even X / Even Y flight:

```
doWork(...);
__syncthreads("one");
__syncthreads("two");
__syncthreads("three");
```

Odd X / Even Y flight:

```
__syncthreads("one");
doWork(...);
__syncthreads("two");
__syncthreads("three");
```

Even X / Odd Y flight:

```
__syncthreads("one");
__syncthreads("two");
doWork(...);
__syncthreads("three");
```

Odd X / Odd Y flight:

```
__syncthreads("one");
__syncthreads("two");
__syncthreads("three");
doWork(...);
```

However, I think that the `__syncthreads()` is not going to do what I want since my application does not appear to be working properly.

Can I somehow identify my synchronization points, such as by name, so that the code has three synchronizations, between pairs of flights as shown in my above example or is there a better way to do this in Cuda?

---

The launch configuration looks like this:

```
const int32_t pixelBlockSize = <argument to function>;
const int32_t pixelGridSize  = <argument to function>;

const size_t scratch   = (pixelBlockSize * pixelBlockSize + 2) * sizeof( float );
const dim3 dimBlock( pixelBlockSize, pixelBlockSize );
const dim3 dimGrid( pixelGridSize, pixelGridSize );

CallKernel<<< dimGrid, dimBlock, scratch >>> ( ... )
```

Comment: What does your launch configuration look like? Do you launch only one block? If you launch multiple blocks, is it guaranteed that the sets of pixels accessed by threads from separate blocks are disjoint? Note that `__syncthreads()` only provides block-level synchronization (see my answer below for more on that). If you need make sure all threads in the whole kernel launch are done before moving on, you will most likely want to just perform multiple kernel launches, e.g., one per flight…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the answer of Michael Kenzel:

```
// We break the threads up into four flights:
//
//     0: even X and even Y
//     1:  odd X and even Y
//     2: even X and  odd Y
//     3:  odd X and  odd Y
const int flight = ( threadIdx.x % 2 + ( ( threadIdx.y % 2 ) << 1 ) );

auto Process = [&](const bool run) {
  if ( run )
    {
      doWork( pixel[ threadIdx.x +     threadIdx.y * blockDim.x ],
              pixel[ threadIdx.x + 1 + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x ],
              pixel[ threadIdx.x + 1 + (threadIdx.y + 1) * blockDim.x ],
              pixel[ threadIdx.x +     (threadIdx.y + 1) * blockDim.x ]);
    }
};

Process( 0 == flight ); __syncthreads();
Process( 1 == flight ); __syncthreads();
Process( 2 == flight ); __syncthreads();
Process( 3 == flight );
```

Comment: Note that this would seem to be a rather inefficient way of doing things. At least if I understand this correctly, only a quarter of your threads will be doing anything at any given point in time. It would seem a better idea to have each thread work on a different set of pixels in each "flight" instead?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, yes, but there is other code (not shown) where all the threads are engaged.

Answer (score 1):

`__syncthreads()` *is* a synchronization point. There is no way to have just a few individual threads synchronize via `__syncthreads()`. Each `__syncthreads()` is a barrier that causes *every* thread in a block to wait until *all* threads of the block have reached the point of the `__syncthreads()`. You cannot have `__syncthreads()` in diverging branches. All (non-exited) threads of a block *must* arrive at each `__syncthreads()`; otherwise, behavior is undefined. While, at the PTX level, [there would be ways](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#parallel-synchronization-and-communication-instructions-bar) to do a bit more fine-grained barrier synchronization, I don't think those really are the answer here. If I understand your problem correctly, then all you're looking for would seem to be

```
doWork(…)
__syncthreads();
doWork(…)
__syncthreads();
doWork(…)
__syncthreads();
doWork(…)
```

All the threads of each block run the initial `doWork(…)` in parallel. You wait until all threads are done with that. Then you run the next `doWork(…)` and so on…

You may, in general, also want to have a look at the [cooperative groups library](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cooperative-groups), which offers a nice abstraction layer on top of the basic CUDA synchronization primitives.

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cooperative-groups and https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions

Comment: @talonmies I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: That while your answer was correct five years ago, it is pretty misleading now. All the PTX level warp synchronization you mentioned are fully exposed in the CUDA C dialect and the cooperative groups functionality provides exactly what the question is asking for -- arbitrary thread work groups with independent synchronization behaviour and collective operations

Comment: @talonmies I was not really talking about warp-level synchronization. OP was asking about block-level synchronization. At least, that's how I understood the question. Note that cooperative groups are essentially just a library wrapper around existing CUDA C and PTX primitives. I'm not aware of a way to define arbitrary intra-block thread groups with independent synchronization behavior like you suggest. By design, cooperative intra-block groups are confined to warp boundaries. You cannot, e.g., have lane 31 of warp 0 synchronize with lane 0 of warp 1 using cooperative groups…

Comment: There's nothing I'm aware you could do using cooperative groups that you can't also do without them. And they come with the same restrictions as the plain CUDA solution. They are just easier and less error-prone to work with (which is, of course, a good thing). Since OP was asking about the behavior of arguably the most basic synchronization mechanism that exists in CUDA, however, I didn't see a reason to bring up the cooperative groups library. I do agree that it won't hurt to mention its existence though…